# c++ reading from anarray of a txt file

Tags: c++, arrays, input

I'm trying to read values from this table written in .txt

```
14, 14.00, 2.00, 1.70
16, 16.00, 2.20, 1.80
18, 18.00, 2.20, 2.00
20, 20.00, 2.30, 2.20
22, 22.00, 2.40, 2.40
24, 24.00, 2.50, 2.50
27, 27.00, 2.60, 2.80
30, 30.00, 2.70, 3.00
35, 35.00, 2.80, 3.40
40, 40.00, 2.90, 3.80
45, 45.00, 3.10, 3.80
50, 50.00, 3.20, 3.80
```

the user is asked to select a value from the first column, the program should then assign the corresponding value in the: 
2nd column to fmk, 3rd column to fc90k and the 4th column to fvk

I have written the program using an answer from another similar question for referance. And it works correctly for the input '14', but then gives unexpected numbers for the other rows.
I am fairly new to c++ so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
cout << "\n\n Please enter the joist strenth class you would like the program to test for,\n eg. for C14, type 14,\n    for C24, type 24 \n     " <<endl;
cin >> beamclass;

cout << "\n\n\n\n\n Thank you, the program shall now compute the beam design using your inputs \n\n\n" << endl;

// F I L E   &   A R R A Y

//this section opens the file, and converts the table into an array
ifstream infile;
infile.open("H:/My Documents/Computing 2/infile.txt");

float a [12][4]; // array starts here
int i;
float value;
char comma;
for (i=0; i<12; i++)
{
for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
{
        infile >> std :: ws >> value;   // 'ws' makes it ignore white space 
        a[i][j] = value;
        if (j != 12) //don't ignore comma for last entry on line bc no comma there
        {
            infile >> std :: ws >> comma; //ignores commas and whitespace
        }
}
}

//this section assigns the desired values from the array to the value name for the following equations

int x = 0;
while (a[x][0]!= beamclass && x<12)
{
    x++ ; 
}

fmyk = a[x][1];
fc90k = a[x][2];
fvk = a[x][3];

cout << "The value of fmky is      " << fmyk << "\n\n" << endl;
cout << "The value of fc90k is     " << fc90k << "\n\n" <<endl;
cout << "The value of fvk is       " << fvk << "\n\n" << endl;
```

Comment: Don't you want `j != 3` in the inner for loop?

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUU

IT WORKKKSSS

You've just given me hope of being able to sleep tonight :D

Comment: The first step in debugging is to try outputting the values that you read in.  You would have immediately seen that you were losing the first character on all lines after the first.  This would have saved you the effort of posting a question here, as well as given you some confidence in your analytical ability.